# How to style KML file boundary lines

Tags: qgis

I'm getting started with QGIS after watching some online videos on this. I'm trying to create a map with satellite imagery and a superimposed KML file of a real estate lot. If I display only the KML file on the canvas you see:

[image]

When I add satellite layer you can barely see the boundary lines:

[image]

How do I change the style of the boundary lines so that they stand out more on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You style KML polygon layers like you would any polygon layer:

Double-click on your KML layer in the layer list.
This will open the layer's properties window:

[image]

On the left there are icons, one of which is called `Symbology`.
In this sub-page you can change how your polygons will look for this layer.

When you select `Fill`, you will see a number of standard fills that you can click-and-use without any work.

For more detailed changes, I selected the `Simple fill` which allows you to change the stroke-width, stroke-type, fill-color and more.

To experiment, it may be easier to use the styling panel:
On top of the layer-list you will see the same symbology icon you see in the layer properties (a paint-brush on top of some colored stripes). Clicking that will open the styling panel. There, you can do the same and see your changes right
away.

To really master this, have a look at the QGIS documentation:
[2.4. Lesson: Symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html)